# Color swatches show up as text on frontend?

Tags: magento2, color-swatches

I created some color swatches, assigend a color from the color picker and saved, that seems to be ok (https://prnt.sc/pi9bm8). After that I assigned the colors to the products.

Now on the frontend, the swatches show the text only, like **010 offwhite**. I reindex, cleared the cache, but nothing works.

Any ideas what I might also try?

**Magento 2.2.3**

**PHP 7.1.3**

Answer (score 0):

make sure you selected **Visual Swatch** as catalog input type.

Set Catalog Input Type for Store Owner to **Visual Swatch**.

Comment: Set Catalog Input Type for Store Owner to Visual Swatch. --> What do you mean?

Comment: I mean this value
https://prnt.sc/pj6jc2